# PayPal Parallel Payments Seller Limits

Tags: php, paypal

I'm thinking about using PayPal Parallel Payments for a market place project however I see that you are limited to 5 sellers per transaction that can receive money. Is there a way to loop through another batch of sellers for payment or would I have to divide the shopping cart into groups of 5 and the buyer would have to checkout each time separately?